# Is it possible to query data while rendering and return its result

Tags: vue.js

When below object is rendered I can do for example something like this:

```
<div v-for="(card, groupIndex) in cards" v-bind:key="card.id">
  <div> {{cards[groupIndex].group.length}} </div>
</div>
```

This will give me the length of each group and render this in a `div`
With below object this will result in 2 divs of which the first will show `4`

```
[
  {
    "id":"BdSxtZL8V4S576i2BTRs",
    "group_name":"nameA",
    "group":[{
      "back":"blabla,
      "delayed_till":{"nanoseconds":0,"seconds":1576729260},
      "examples":[{
        "answer":"blabla",
        "example":"blabla"
      }],
      "front":"blabla"
    },
    {
      "back":"blabla",
      "delayed_till":{"nanoseconds":0,"seconds":1095337800},
      "examples":[{
        "answer":"blabla",
        "example":"blabla"
      }],
      "front":"blabla"
    },
    {
      "back":"blabla",
      "delayed_till":{"nanoseconds":0,"seconds":1577219040},
      "examples":[
      ],
      "front":"blabla"
    },
    {
      "back":"blabla",
      "delayed_till":{"nanoseconds":0,"seconds":1577092680},
      "examples":[{
        "answer":"blabla",
        "example":"blablao"
     }],
    "front":"blabla"
    }]
  },
  {
    "id":"UtKzLYBPygu6iWOb1KMt",
    "group_name":"nameB",
    "group":[
       etc.etc.etc..............
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to be able to render the number of items per group for which the date has not been passed yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your exact same logic here, and just use a function below and pass in the group which applies a filter to the object collection and uses the `delayed_till.seconds` property to determine the validity check, something like this:

```
<div v-for="(card, groupIndex) in cards" v-bind:key="card.id">
  <div v-text="groupItemsNotDelayed(cards[groupIndex].group)"> </div>
</div>
```

Then make your function which performs the filter:

```
groupItemsNotDelayed(group) {
    return group.filter((item) => item.delayed_till.seconds < Date.now()).length
}
```

By using `Date.now()` we can get the current time in UTC Epoch, and compare that against our `item.delayed_till.seconds` to determine if the delayed period has passed (it would have to be less than the current epoch timestamp).

Then we can just call `.length` on the filtered items to get the count.

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy that worked. I had to change a small thing to get it working `groupItemsNotDelayed (group) {
      console.log(Date.now())
      let now = new Date().getTime() / 1000
      return group.filter((item) => item.delayed_till.seconds < now).length
    },`